# Getting an error while requesting a double from another class

Tags: java, class, double

I need to make a menu so the user can choose what he wants to do with the bank app I am building.
user has the following options:

```
>1. Select a bank account. 
>2. Check the account balance.
>3. Depositing money into the account 
>4. Withdraw money from the account
>5. Transfer money from one account to another account
```

To enable this functionality we will add the following methods to the BankAccountService as you can see in the UML scheme below.

```
>1. getAccount (String accountNumber)
>2. getAccountBalance (Account account)
>3. deposit (Account account, double amount)
>4. withdraw (Account account, double amount) 
>5. transfer (Account source, Account target, double amount)
```

[UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Fo7.png)

```
package BankProject;

import java.util.*;

public class BankAccountService {
    private BankAccount[] accounts;

public void addBankAccount(final BankAccount account)
{
    if (accounts == null)
    {
        accounts = new BankAccount[10];
    }

    int index = 0;

    while (accounts[index] != null)
    {
        index++;

        if (index >= accounts.length)
        {
            accounts = Arrays.copyOf(accounts, accounts.length + 10);
        }
    }

    accounts[index] = account;


}


public void getAccountBalance(final BankAccount account) {
    double getAccountBalance = new BankAccount(getAccountBalance());
}
}
```

As you can I get an error when I try to add the method.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxnji.png)

Please keep in mind that I have never coded before and I have no idea why this error is showing.
Can anyone tell me the right way to add this method?

I did figure out a way to get all the account balances in the main folder by adding this code:

```
double balance = bankAccountService.getAccountBalance();
System.out.println(balance);
double balance2 = account1.balance;
System.out.println(balance2);
double balance3 = account2.balance;
System.out.println(balance3);
```

But in the UML it is asking me to add the code in BankAccountService.
I have no clue why this is needed if can do it from main.

Answer (score 0):

If the balance property in BankAccount is private you should create a getter for it and then :

```
public void getAccountBalance(BankAccount account) {
    double accountBalance = account.getBalance();
}
```

So in BankAccount.java you should add:

```
public double getBalance() {
   return this.balance;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,
I should be able to this then?


   `public void getAccountBalance(BankAccount account) {
        double accountBalance = account.getBalance();
    }
    public void deposit (BankAccount account) {
        double depositAmount = account.deposit();
    }
    public void withdraw (BankAccount account) {
        double withdrawAmount = account.withdraw();
    }
    public void transfer (BankAccount account) {
        double transferAmount = account.transfer();
    }`

Comment: Yes, but be sure to write a public function for each one in the BankAccount.java. And for the deposit it should have an input of double like: 
`public void deposit(double amount) {
     this.balance += amount;
}`
And use it in the service:
`public void deposit(BankAccount account, double amount) {
      account.deposit(amount);
}`

And because you change the value of the properties don't use the final keyword.